# Looking for a decent free opensource php grid preferable BSD or MIT licensed

Tags: php, joomla, grid, reporting

I'm relatively new to php and I've been given the task of generating a tabular report.
I have to be able to do the following with the grid.

Fully stylable
Specify a SQL statement for the data
Choose the columns that I want display (alias names for columns would be really nice too)
Sorting and n-level Grouping on columns

Also, my company is looking at keeping the code propriety.
I should also mention that this will be running in a joomla site so joomla reporting components suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with PHP nor with programming in general as it's just 'gimme teh codez' one

Comment: I'm looking for a PHP generated DataGrid control. If this is not the right place to ask this question do you have any suggestions where I should put this? Perhaps the PHP forums?

Comment: PHP forums is wrong place either. a good fairy or wizard probably would help to get full-featured, stable, well-supported and free application suits all your whims.

Comment: I usually don't entertain flame wars online, but SO is a site to help people and provide answers to questions. My question, although not a technical question about the language or its semantics itself is a valid question. If you don't care to answer it, or have no helpful or positive critique please refrain from commenting. If on the other hand you have something useful to contribute, I would love to see an answer. Patronizing SO users is not a very kind thing to do.

Comment: It was merely a suggestion. If you don't like it, just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you look at simply getting the data yourself using your normal data access, outputting it in JSON format and using a UI component like [jQuery Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) to display the resulting data. The datatables component is dual licensed under GPLv2 and BSD (3 point) licenses.

Alternatively you could look at a component such as [phpGrid](http://phpgrid.com/), but this is not free.

Comment: phpGrid looks like a good solution for what I want. Does it support grouping without having to pay the $50?

Comment: No. From their website "Features including edit, master detail, grouping, and reference to multiple databases are only available in paid versions."

Comment: jqgrid looks pretty neat too.

Comment: phpGrid led me to jqGrid which suits my current and future needs. Thanks Shane.